# Gmlib maps api. When we resize TWebBrowser to full screen, map is working very very slowly

Tags: google-maps-api-3, gmlib

Yesterday, we encountered a problem with Gmlib maps api. When we resize TWebBrowser to full screen, map is working very very slowly, but if map is in small size e.g. 600x600, everything works pretty good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put 3.33 instead of 3.27 (3.35  won t work) in the map.htlm (in the resources folder)

Lunch rc.cmd then rebuild gmlib and all ok.

Comment: if u have Chromium embedded, u need to tweek the css in order to not have those scrolls bars